# configuración correcta mysql server

Tags: mysql, mariadb

tengo la siguiente configuracion en mariadb:
Versión del servidor: 10.0.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - Ubuntu 16.04
vps: 100 gb dd y 8gb de ram

[image: estadisticas de consultas]

Ahora mi configuracion de servidor mysql:

```
buffer sizes
key_buffer_size         = 100M
sort_buffer_size        = 5M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
join_buffer_size        = 2M

connection setting
max_connections        = 200
max_connect_errors      = 10
wait_timeout            = 30
connect_timeout         = 10
interactive_timeout     = 60

Query Cache Configuration

query_cache_limit   = 500M
query_cache_size        = 400M
query_cache_type        = 1
table_open_cache        = 5000
thread_cache_size       = 100

tmpdir / temp table sizes
tmp_table_size          = 256M
max_heap_table_size     = 256M

max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 100
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
```

Mi servidor mysql esta bajo mucha presion, ya que se realizan gran cantidad de consultas, y cada 4 dias debo reiniciarlo, para que libere memoria del disco duro ya que lo llena constantemente y no se de que. Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: 8 gb de memoria parecen poco